# How do I use parse a string with wildcards?

Tags: r

How do I parse/extract information from a string in r with wildcards?

```
head(df)
set           type
a             [OutofArea]:[type:"928"]:[idnum:"27"]
a             [WithinRange]:[type:"029":[...
a             [OutofArea]:[type:"928"]:[...
a             [OutofArea]:[type:"274"]:[...
a             [OutofArea]:[type:"210"]:[...
a             [OutofArea]:[type:"199"]"[...
```

I just need the numeric information after type. 
So just the 928, 029, etc. In this case, the numbers are the wildcards- anything after type:" and before the next "

Comment: Is it a `list` column or   `character` class

Comment: character class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `sub`

```
sub('.*type:"(\\d+)".*', '\\1', df$type)
#[1] "928" "029" "928" "274" "210" "199"
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(set = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a"), 
     type = c("[OutofArea]:[type:\"928\"]:[idnum:\"27\"]", 
"[WithinRange]:[type:\"029\":", "[OutofArea]:[type:\"928\"]:", 
"[OutofArea]:[type:\"274\"]:", "[OutofArea]:[type:\"210\"]:", 
"[OutofArea]:[type:\"199\"]\"")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-6L))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `str_extract` to extract the digits after the 'type:' string

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate(new = str_extract(type, '(?<=type:")\\d+'))
#  set                                   type new
#1   a  [OutofArea]:[type:"928"]:[idnum:"27"] 928
#2   a [WithinRange]:[type:"029":[idnum:"27"] 029
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(set = c("a", "a"), type = c("[OutofArea]:[type:\"928\"]:[idnum:\"27\"]", 
"[WithinRange]:[type:\"029\":[idnum:\"27\"]")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: I end up getting this error Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "character"

Comment: @NBB Can you show the error as I used the data in my post

Comment: @NBB `mutate` doesn't have any issue with `character` class.  Can you check the `str(df)` and compare  with the `str(df)`  in my post

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data shown reproducibly in the Note at the end we can use `read.table` with `sep` equal to double quote and then pick off the second field.    This returns the numbers as numeric but if you want them as character then add `colClasses = "character"` to the `read.table` arguments.  No packages or regular expressions are used.

```
read.table(text = df$type, sep = '"', quote = '', fill = TRUE)[[2]]
## [1] 928  29 928 274 210 199
```

### Note

```
Lines <- 'set           type
a             [OutofArea]:[type:"928"]:[idnum:"27"]
a             [WithinRange]:[type:"029":[...
a             [OutofArea]:[type:"928"]:[...
a             [OutofArea]:[type:"274"]:[...
a             [OutofArea]:[type:"210"]:[...
a             [OutofArea]:[type:"199"]"[...'
df <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
```